# Are these symptoms of a video card is dying?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card

What I am getting from my PC:

1. Scrambled text in the boot menu.
2. The scrambled text dissapears and everthing goes normal after several restarts, or the computer has worked for some time.
3. Display goes blank showing, windows kernel mode driver stopped responding.
4. Sometimes the windows just hangs, I need to restart the pc for that.
5. There used to be some scrambled colours in my windows, so I cleaned up my video card and port and reinstalled the video card, things are something right.
6. The pc runs normally for hours in safe mode, as default display driver works at that case.

My PC specs:

- Core 2 Duo processor
- 2 GB RAM
- NVIDIA EN210 SILENT card.
- Windows 8

Drivers details: NVIDIA drivers - v331.65, told to be fully compatible with Win8

Currently I am installing Windows 7 and will be putting the older version of driver v320 to test, yet I'm really confused weather my GPU is dying or still on go.

Comment: Probably yes. Borrow another graphics card and see if it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1. Scrambled text in the boot menu.

I'm assuming this means the initial BIOS or UEFI screen.  Press the hot hey on your system to get into the BIOS or firmware menu (F12 is typical for Dell's).  If you see scrambled text or graphics at that point it rules out any OS or driver issues.

If this happens when your monitor is connected to the video card, but NOT when it's connected to the integrated video connector on the motherboard, then I would heavily suspect the video card is bad OR the slot that it's in is bad.  Second most likely cause would be a general motherboard issue and third most likely would be a power supply issue.

Comment: Hey, thanks, but what could be the possibility if without the graphics card driver installed everthing is going smooth, speaking of the safe mode, the first point can also be the cause created by the driver till some new installation is done, I read such things while googling.

Comment: When only the VGA-compatible graphics driver is being used (i.e., no graphics driver), no hardware acceleration is taking place.  Typically when you install the nVidia or ATI driver, then Windows uses some GPU acceleration for the GUI.  So I imagine most of the video card is not running or active in plain VGA compatible mode.  Even though Windows hardly stresses the GPU compared to games, once the proper driver is there, it may be enough to push a teetering card over the edge.